# Line fill for UITextView?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, text-formatting

Is there a property that will apply the proper character spacing to have all the text on each line in an NSAttributedString butt up against the bounds like in a book, (including the final line which I know isn't done in books)? I know kerning can be adjusted, but that won't dynamically adjust on a per line basis. Any help would be appreciated. Also NSTextAlignmentJustified and NSTextAlignmentNatural get close, but won't apply the effect to the last line of text.

Comment: Did you look at the docs for `UITextView`? Hint - `textAlignment`

Comment: Text alignment is left, right or center. None of which would align the text on the left side of the line of text to the left bounds, and the text on the right to align on the right bounds.

Comment: Again, have you read the docs on the `UITextView textAlignment` property? It has more values than you claim.

Comment: I also tried NSTextAlignmentJustified and NSTextAlignmentNatural, which also did not produce the results I was after.

Comment: Strange, I'm playing with this and I get left alignment no matter which value I use. Are you setting the text view's `text` or `attributedText` property?

Comment: I'm setting the paragraphStyle property of the attributed string. If I use NSTextAlignmentJustified or NSTextAlignmentNatural, most of the lines achieve what I want, but the last line always ends up left or right justified. Also, seeing as I've shown that I had done the research, I'd appreciate removing any down votes.

Comment: As written, your question still deserves some down votes. Update your question showing more effort and more details. As written it doesn't even look like you checked the docs. Now, based on your last comment, you are doing something completely different than what your question covers. Working with attributed text is quite different from simply setting the `textAlignment` property of the text view.

Comment: And BTW - the last line of justified text is never justified. Look at any book.

Answer (score 0):

The only option is to use `NSTextAlignmentJustified`. Last line is never justified, because `NSTextAlignmentJustified` refers to `Left Justification` mode, as it is the standard case.

For more information you can take a look at `Typographic Alignment` on wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment